# Array index out of bound in Android

Tags: android

I am getting following exception on crashlytics. Please help me out to resolve this issue

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
length=3; index=3
android.util.ContainerHelpers.binarySearch (ContainerHelpers.java:47)
android.util.LongSparseArray.get (LongSparseArray.java:113)
android.util.LongSparseArray.get (LongSparseArray.java:104)
android.graphics.Typeface.create (Typeface.java:177)
arrow_right
android.support.v4.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi24Impl.createFromFontInfo (Unknown Source)
android.support.v4.graphics.TypefaceCompat.createFromFontInfo (Unknown Source)
android.support.v4.provider.FontsContractCompat.buildTypeface (Unknown Source)
android.support.v4.provider.FontsContractCompat$4.run (Unknown Source)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:761)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:156)
android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I think this issue is related to typeFace in android, as in written in above exception

```
"android.support.v4.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi24Impl.createFromFontInfo (Unknown Source)"
```

I am using following class to set the text fonts. Please have look at the following class.

```html
public class CustomTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);

    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    public void init(AttributeSet attrs) {


        try {
            if (getContext()!=null &&attrs != null) {
                TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView);
                String fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomTextView_fontName);

                if (fontName != null) {
                    requestDownload(fontName);
                }
                a.recycle();
            }

            this.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setTypeFaceBold() {
        try {
            requestDownload("poppinsbold.ttf");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    public void setTypeFaceLight() {
        try {
            requestDownload("poppinslight.ttf");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    }

    public void setTypeFaceMedium() {
        try {
            requestDownload("poppinsmedium.ttf");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void setTypeFaceRegular() {
        try {
            requestDownload("poppinsregular.ttf");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void setTypeFaceSemiBold() {
        try {
            requestDownload("poppinssemibold.ttf");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    private Handler mHandler = null;

    private void requestDownload(final String familyName) {
        try {
            int widthValue = (int) (100 * (float) FontConstants.WIDTH_DEFAULT / (float) FontConstants.WIDTH_MAX);
            float weightValue = (float) FontConstants.WEIGHT_DEFAULT / (float) FontConstants.WEIGHT_MAX * 100;
            float italicValue = (float) FontConstants.ITALIC_DEFAULT;

            if (familyName.equals("poppinslight.ttf")) {
                weightValue = 300;
                if(BaseActivity.poppins_light!=null){
                    this.setTypeface(BaseActivity.poppins_light);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (familyName.equals("poppinsmedium.ttf")) {
                weightValue = 500;
                if(BaseActivity.poppins_medium!=null){
                    this.setTypeface(BaseActivity.poppins_medium);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (familyName.equals("poppinsregular.ttf")) {
                weightValue = 400;
                if(BaseActivity.poppins!=null){
                    this.setTypeface(BaseActivity.poppins);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (familyName.equals("poppinssemibold.ttf")) {
                weightValue = 600;
                if(BaseActivity.poppins_semibold!=null){
                    this.setTypeface(BaseActivity.poppins_semibold);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (familyName.equals("poppinsbold.ttf")) {
                weightValue = 700;
                if(BaseActivity.poppins_bold!=null){
                    this.setTypeface(BaseActivity.poppins_bold);
                    return;
                }
            }

            QueryBuilder queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder("Poppins")
                    .withWidth(widthValue)
                    .withWeight((int) weightValue)
                    .withItalic(italicValue)
                    .withBestEffort(true);

            String query = queryBuilder.build();

            FontRequest request = new FontRequest(
                    "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
                    "com.google.android.gms",
                    query,
                    R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs);

            FontsContractCompat.FontRequestCallback callback = new FontsContractCompat.FontRequestCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onTypefaceRetrieved(Typeface typeface) {
                    try {
                        if (familyName.equals("poppinslight.ttf")) {
                            BaseActivity.poppins_light = typeface;
                        } else if (familyName.equals("poppinsmedium.ttf")) {
                            BaseActivity.poppins_medium = typeface;
                        } else if (familyName.equals("poppinsregular.ttf")) {
                            BaseActivity.poppins = typeface;
                        } else if (familyName.equals("poppinssemibold.ttf")) {
                            BaseActivity.poppins_semibold = typeface;
                        } else if (familyName.equals("poppinsbold.ttf")) {
                            BaseActivity.poppins_bold = typeface;
                        }


                        CustomTextView.this.setTypeface(typeface);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onTypefaceRequestFailed(int reason) {
                    Log.d("font", "failed");
                    /**
                     * Failed
                     */
                }
            };
            FontsContractCompat
                    .requestFont(getContext(), request, callback,
                            getHandlerThreadHandler());
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Handler getHandlerThreadHandler() {
        try{
            if (mHandler == null) {
                HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("fonts");
                handlerThread.start();
                mHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mHandler;
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you're trying to access element at index 3, which is actually the 4th item in the collection. If you want to get the third element of the list you should ask for item at index 2. Also try to wrap all of that into try-catch

Comment: We need some code to help. 
Also read the documentation: 
"Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array."

Comment: @ScottChambers Thankyou for your response. I think this issue is related to Typefaces in android. I have provided the stack trace copied from crashlytics. I am not sure which part of code causing this exception.

Comment: Show some code where error occur for we can help you better

Comment: @DiegoVenâncio I have added the code, that I think is causing the exception. Please review the class that I have provided in my question.Thanks

Comment: @Ehsan Anjum. Before using this 'a' after declaration you can test something like "if(a != null || a.size > 0){} ?

Comment: @DiegoVenâncio Thankyou so much, one last thing I want to know that this piece of code is properly handled inside a try catch block then why does this code generates a crash on crashlytics.

Comment: @Ehsan Anjum choose a better response for this question for close it and make other question for try catch.

Comment: Hi @EhsanAnjum Did you find a solution for the issue. We are facing the exact same issue in our app, and have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: @sanjeev didn't found any solution to this problem but a way around to this issue is to set the Font Family in XML layouts.

Comment: We are facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

If you come here with the same Exception but yours has nothing related to any library and you see something like:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=11; index=11
at android.util.ContainerHelpers.binarySearch(ContainerHelpers.java:28)
at android.util.SparseIntArray.get(SparseIntArray.java:108)
```

The issue is inside of SparseArray. The only solution I found it's replace SparseArray with HashMap to avoid the BinarySearch operations.

Here is link to useful Github [issue](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9830). [Here](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/commit/155ed686dc63f8bc6cb16fac54a4ce95629bf4bd) you can find the commit and it seems to fix the problem.

If the issue happens inside of some library - try to update to the latest version OR temporarily downgrade the version and watch on updates.

Answer (score -2):

As per logs:

```
length=3; index=3
```

Your **array length is 3** and you are trying to **get index of 3**. Check if your counter starts from 0 or your exit condition is proper.

Comment: thankyou for your response. I am not using any array, this exception is related to Typeface. I have no idea how to resolve this issue. please guide if you know the solution. Thanks

Comment: Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
length=3; index=3 Your error indicate was using some array in some place.

Answer (score -2):

Fatal Exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
length=3; index=3
```

This exception you are getting because your array list or array having only only 3 items but you want to access the item of index 3 means forth item that is not exist in your item list.

So before accessing particular item please make one condition.

Like the index should not be bigger than the list size:

```
if (index < arraylist.size()) {
   // Then access here your item From list
}
```

Answer (score -2):

UPDATE:

Test your 'a' [array lenght](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) before use it.

```
new TypedArray(buffer [, byteOffset [, length]]);
```

---

double[] myList = new double[10];

Check that my list have 10 positions but in image we can access to `myList[9]` because index start in `myList[0]`

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Use something like this

```
for(int a = 0; a <= presList.size()-1; a++)
```